# What in this php switch statement is breaking my code?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

This code snippet is just a small part of a larger php file. Currently, the file produces nothing when run (as befits PHP) but when I comment out this section (below), the file executes. Thus, I'm left to believe that something in this code snippet is keeping the PHP from running correctly. Perhaps is it the nested switch-statements?

```
switch($interval)
{
    case "week":

        $active_date = date('N', $endTime);

        switch($active_date)
        {
            case 1:
                $categories = ["Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday"];
                break;
            case 2:
                $categories = ["Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday"];
                break;
            case 3:
                $categories = ["Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
                break;
            case 4:
                $categories = ["Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"];
                break;
            case 5:
                $categories = ["Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"];
                break;
            case 6:
                $categories = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
                break;
            case 7:
                $categories = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "month":
        $categories = ["Three Weeks Ago","Two Weeks Ago","Last Week","This Week"];
        break;
    case "year":

        $active_date = date('n', $endTime);

        switch($active_date)
        {
            case 1:
                $categories = ["February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January"];
                break;
            case 2:
                $categories = ["March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February"];
                break;
            case 3:
                $categories = ["April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March"];
                break;
            case 4:
                $categories = ["May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April"];
                break;
            case 5:
                $categories = ["June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May"];
                break;
            case 6:
                $categories = ["July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June"];
                break;
            case 7:
                $categories = ["August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July"];
                break;
            case 8:
                $categories = ["September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August"];
                break;
            case 9:
                $categories = ["October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September"];
                break;
            case 10:
                $categories = ["November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October"];
                break;
            case 11:
                $categories = ["December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November"];
                break;
            case 12:
                $categories = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

any idea what is incorrect about this?

Comment: Where is `$endTime` defined?

Comment: Addition to @relentless , can you put `var_dump($interval);` before `switch` ?

Comment: BTW, It's working good ?

Comment: $endTime is defined in an earlier part of the code, as 1354044453 (for testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, I was hinted to try using the array() syntax instead of the [ ] syntax and that appears to have the code working. So I'll assume that as a solution for now.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the last Breaks of each case:

```
switch($interval)
{case "week":

    $active_date = date('N', $endTime);

    switch($active_date)
    {
        case 1:
            $categories = ["Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday"];
            break;
        case 2:
            $categories = ["Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday"];
            break;
        case 3:
            $categories = ["Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
            break;
        case 4:
            $categories = ["Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"];
            break;
        case 5:
            $categories = ["Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"];
            break;
        case 6:
            $categories = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
            break;
        case 7:
            $categories = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
    }
    break;
case "month":
    $categories = ["Three Weeks Ago","Two Weeks Ago","Last Week","This Week"];
    break;
case "year":

    $active_date = date('n', $endTime);

    switch($active_date)
    {
        case 1:
            $categories = ["February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January"];
            break;
        case 2:
            $categories = ["March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February"];
            break;
        case 3:
            $categories = ["April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March"];
            break;
        case 4:
            $categories = ["May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April"];
            break;
        case 5:
            $categories = ["June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May"];
            break;
        case 6:
            $categories = ["July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June"];
            break;
        case 7:
            $categories = ["August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July"];
            break;
        case 8:
            $categories = ["September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August"];
            break;
        case 9:
            $categories = ["October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September"];
            break;
        case 10:
            $categories = ["November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October"];
            break;
        case 11:
            $categories = ["December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November"];
            break;
        case 12:
            $categories = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
    }
}
```